# Responsive Container/ layout

Tags: html, containers

I'm trying to make a responsive layout for images and text together. The pictures are responsive, however, the text gets smashed on smaller devices. Please help!

```html
   
<h3><strong> </strong></h3>
<div style="width: 60%; padding: 0 10 pt 0 0; float: left;">
<h3><strong>Contact a Manager to Learn More!</strong></h3>


<h3>Arizona Offices:</h3>
<p><img style="float: left;" class="img-responsive" src="/media/3559/lettyhuffman.png?width=158&amp;height=216" alt="letty.huffman.png" rel="6743" /></p>
   
<p> </p>
</div>
<div style="width: 40%; padding: 0 10pt 0 0; float: right;">
<p><br /><br /><br /><br /><img style="float: left;" src="/media/3564/gerifarr.png?width=158&amp;height=216" alt="Geri.Farr.png" rel="6748" /></p>
<h4> Phoenix:</h4>
<h5><strong> Geri </strong></h5>
<p><span style="line-height: 1.42857143;"> Regional Manager</span></p>

<p style="padding-left: 150px;"><span style="line-height: 1.42857143;"> Fax: 602.224.4842 </span></p>
<p> </p>
</div>
<div style="width: 60%; padding: 0 10 pt 0 0; float: left;">
<p><img style="float: left;" src="/media/3549/no_photo_female.png?width=158&amp;; height=216" alt="JPM" rel="" /></p>
<h4> Maricopa County:</h4>
<h5><strong> Jessica Paquette- Maxwell</strong></h5>
<p> Maricopa County Talent Acquisition Manager</p>
   
</div>
<div style="width: 40%; padding: 0 10pt 0 0; float: right;">
<p><img style="float: left;" src="/media/3562/dianahillman.png?width=158&amp;height=216" alt="Diana.Hillman.png" rel="6746" /></p>
<h4> Tucson &amp; Yuma:</h4>
<h5><strong> Diana </strong></h5>
<p><span style="line-height: 1.42857143;"> Vice President &amp; Branch Manager</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a very similar question from someone else, this is what I wrote:

You could look into CSS feature called @media rule, example: 
`@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { font-size:20px; }`

This way you can add css properties to your stylesheet which only come into affect once the browser reaches that certain minimum width. It's in my opinion the best way to make any website responsive. No javascript required, nor do you have to create an entire new website on a subdomain, like many websites do.

Just FYI, anything that is inside the media rule, will be added or will overwrite the current style sheet, so you don't have to duplicate every entry you have so far, only the ones you want to add/change.

Regarding font-size. I usually go for 16-20px on screens below 800px width, which is mostly smartphones.